# why i am not able to access Panel class in Pandas library?

Tags: python

i am trying to use Panel() in pandas library but getting below error :

```
runfile('E:/Pytjhon pandas library/panel.py', wdir='E:/Pytjhon pandas library')
<pandas.__getattr__.<locals>.Panel object at 0x000001C81854A2C8>
E:/Pytjhon pandas library/panel.py:10: FutureWarning: The Panel class is removed from pandas. Accessing it from the top-level namespace will also be removed in the next version
  p=pd.Panel()
```

Comment: What part of 'The Panel class is removed from pandas. Accessing it from the top-level namespace will also be removed in the next version
  p=pd.Panel()" do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

Panel was deprecated in Pandas version 0.20.0.